# Arduino OneWire on multiple pins by index (Array of OneWire Objects)?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to implement an Arduino project with multiple thermometers (DS18x20) on multiple GPIO pins.  I'm using the OneWire library (http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OneWire.html).  I want to easily switch between pins, preferrably referring to the pin objects by index from an array of pin objects.  I am NOT a C++ programmer, and I do not know how to do this.

I actually have managed to come up with a workaround by hacking the library, but it is definitely a HACK and NOT proper C++ coding.  I would like to know how to do it correctly.

The OneWire Library object constructor for a pin object "ds" is: `OneWire ds(pinNum);`

This creates the object and sets up a few variables ... nothing exotic.

Calling a function, such as "reset" is: `ds.reset();`

I want to be able to easily switch back and forth between the pins performing the various DS18B20 thermometer functions.  The only suggestion I found for multiple pins is to create multiple objects, but that means separate calls for each and every operation, like: `ds1.reset(); ds2.reset(); //etc.`

My HACK got around this by writing and inserting a function "apin(pinNum)" which identically is the same code as the constructor, but is not a constructor, but a callable function.  This new function was added to **OneWire.h**, **OneWire.cpp**, and **keywords.txt**.  So if you define the pin object as "ds", a call to: `ds.apin(pinNum)` "changes" the pin object to the new pin.  You can put the pin numbers in an array and call "apin" by the array elements index, such as with: `ds.apin(pinNum[i]);`

The hack works fine, but it is bad C++ practice.

What would be, I think, GOOD C++ practice is to somehow create an array of OneWire objects for the pin array, so that you can call functions by object index like: `ds[i].reset`.  The problem is how to implement the array and the constructor ???

Here is a little bit of code basically showing how to run a single pin ... you can see how messy it would be to have 2 or more of EVERY call:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
int     pinNum[] = { 9, 10 };  // Array of pins that can be used
uint8_t addr[8];   // array of bytes for the 64 bit device address
byte    data[12];  // Raw data from read of Scratch Pad    

void setup(void) {
    OneWire ds(pinNum[1]); // Constructor for object ds(10)
    ds.reset();
    ds.search(addr);       // find device address, put in array addr
    ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);       // Issue the address of the current device
    ds.write(0x44,0);      // Start the conversion

    delay(775);            // Wait at least 750 milliseconds

    ds.write(0xBE);        // Read the device Scratchpad
    // Read 9 bytes of Scratch Pad Data
    for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        data[k] = ds.read();
    }

}
```

Thank you for any and all comments, suggestions, and assistance in this effort.

Blessings in abundance, all the best, & ENJOY!
Art in Carlisle, PA USA  (Webtest)